# Update method in Java similar to XNA

Tags: java, timer

I'm currently making a Java app that requires me to display a live timer on screen. I have created the timer successfully and it updates on a button press. However I want it to constantly be updating itself.

Is it possible to make an update method similar to the one used in XNA? I want it to call itself a number of times a second.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in the context of a Swing application, you should use Swing Timer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Here is a tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have already tried implementing this, but appear to be having some trouble. I will give it another go though. I assumed that there would be some kind of built in update method.